# two arrays point to the same information

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have two arrays
after some changes in second array i want to have
first array the same as second,
is it possible not to copy the whole array one by one element
but somehow by one command make first array point to elements of
second array.

Comment: chick this link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy
What you need is a Shallow Copy like shown in this picture, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Shallow_copy_in_progress.svg
use two pointers.

Comment: Is this a poem?

Answer (score 6):

No, an array is an object and on object is some region of storage. Two arrays are two separate regions of storage.

However, given a pointer to the first element of an array, you can use it to index the array just as you would with the array itself:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int* p = arr;
arr[2] == p[2];
```

I don't want to fuel the misconception that arrays and pointers are similar in any way, however. The first line defines an array object containing 5 `int`s. The second line defines a pointer that points to the first element in that array.

The reason they can both be used in the same way in the last line is because the name of the array, `arr`, is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element before doing the indexing. So really those two sub-expressions are the same thing. `arr[2]` just involves an implicit conversion to a pointer before applying the indexing operator.

Alternatively, you can take a reference to an array:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int (&r)[5] = arr;
arr[2] == r[2];
```

Now `r` is just an alias for the array. Both `arr` and `r` literally refer to the array object.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to copy one element at a time, a simple `for` loop will do. If you want to copy all elements you could use e.g. `memcpy` (if, and only **if** your arrays have POD types).

Then there's of course [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
int array1[5] = { ... };
int array2[5];

// Copy from `array1` to `array2`
std::copy(std::begin(array1), std::end(array1), std::begin(array2));
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Re-reading it a couple of times, you're probably right.